# Local node webcontainer adapter for sveltekit. Looking for an example

Tags: node.js, adapter, svelte, sveltekit, web-container

I like to use and experiment with the [StackBlitz webcontainer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webcontainer/api) in my browser to create a "local" Sveltekit app. Local: running node in my browser.

I'am looking for an example or even better: an adapter.

Like to know more? I found [this nice intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5WnVPwsOFg) from Tejas Kumar.